# DataTable Join or Merge

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have 3 Data tables populated with a dataset and table adapters/ binding sources and i need to run a Join query or find another way to get specific data. (the dataset contains each table listed)

Tables:

Product Table:

```
Prod_ID    Name    

1          tv
2          couch
```

Consumer Table:

```
Con_Id    Name    City
----------------------
1         Gray    New York
2         Joe     Chicago
3         Steve   Madison
```

Transactions Table

```
Tran_Id   Con_ID    Prod_ID    Price
-------------------------------------
1         2         1          900
2         1         2          300
```

Given a product name i need to populate a table with each distinct city and how much that product has sold for in that city (add all prices for that product to any consumer in a given city)

I am really stumped and cant find a way. (i have tried alot)
Please help and thank you!

Nudiers approach so far:

```
            DataRelation relation = null;
            DataColumn table1Column = null;
            DataColumn table2Column = null;
            DataColumn table3Column = null;

            table1Column = tlobergeDataSet.Tb_Product.Columns[0];
            table2Column = tlobergeDataSet.Tb_Transactions.Columns[3];
            table3Column = tlobergeDataSet.Tb_Consumer.Columns[0];

            relation = new DataRelation("relation", table1Column, table2Column);
            tlobergeDataSet.Relations.Add(relation);
```

Comment: It is the las tpart to my homework. I have tried creating 3 dimensional arrays and populating it with the data so there were no duplicates, i tried running select statements on each table to return the correct info (cant find out how to add values after). The teacher said it  could be done easily using linq but i am not familiar with it and i cant get that to work either.

Comment: have you tried the relations property of the dataset object?

Comment: Start by looking at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b and trying to create your own code. Post your code and we can help you identify where you went wrong if you still have problems.

Comment: @Nudier I have looked at it but the MSDN doesn't give any examples and i cant figure out how to apply it

Comment: Also, from your description, it sounds like you are looking for a group by with an aggregate.

Comment: this is an example how you can achieve that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
    public DataTable MergeTables(DataTable dtFirst, DataTable dtSecond, string CommonColumn)
    {
        DataTable dtResults = dtFirst.Clone();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtSecond.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!dtFirst.Columns.Contains(dtSecond.Columns[i].ColumnName))
            {
                dtResults.Columns.Add(dtSecond.Columns[i].ColumnName, dtSecond.Columns[i].DataType);
                count++;
            }
        }

        DataColumn[] columns = new DataColumn[count];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtSecond.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!dtFirst.Columns.Contains(dtSecond.Columns[i].ColumnName))
            {
                columns[j++] = new DataColumn(dtSecond.Columns[i].ColumnName, dtSecond.Columns[i].DataType);
            }
        }

        dtResults.BeginLoadData();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtFirst.Rows)
        {
            dtResults.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtSecond.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr1 in dtResults.Rows)
            {
                if (dr1[CommonColumn].ToString().Equals(dr[CommonColumn].ToString()))
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn c in columns)
                    {
                        dr1[c.ColumnName] = dr[c.ColumnName];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dtResults.EndLoadData();
        return dtResults;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ, you can join the tables to find the data you want with syntax like so:

```
from a in keyTable
join b in anotherTable on a.Key equals b.Key
join c in aThirdTable on a.Key equals c.Key
select new
{
    // Anonymous Object Properties using identifier a, b, and c to get data
};
```

You should be able to take that snippet and generate a linq query that will generate an anonymous object containing the specific data representation that you need.

Comment: Are a,b, and c the columns? And how would i go about selecting distinct cities with their price values added up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
DataRelation relation = null;
DataColumn table1Column = null;
DataColumn table2Column = null;
//retrieve column
table1Column = ds.Tables("Table1").Columns(0);
table2Column = ds.Tables("table2").Columns(0);
//relating tables
relation = new DataRelation("relation", table1Column, table2Column);
//assign relation to dataset
ds.Relations.Add(relation);
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the relations to 3 tables? And how do i access the data from here?

Answer (score 0):

You can only relate two tables in a DataRelation object and to access the data from
 the dataset is straightforward because the data has been already related.

```
        DataRelation relation = null;
        DataColumn table1Column = null;
        DataColumn table2Column = null;
        DataColumn table3Column = null;

        table1Column = tlobergeDataSet.Tb_Product.Columns[0];
        table2Column = tlobergeDataSet.Tb_Transactions.Columns[2];
        table2Column1 = tlobergeDataSet.Tb_Transactions.Columns[1];
        table3Column = tlobergeDataSet.Tb_Consumer.Columns[0];

        relation = new DataRelation("relation", table1Column, table2Column);
        tlobergeDataSet.Relations.Add(relation);

       relation = new DataRelation("relation1", table3Column , table2Column1);
       tlobergeDataSet.Relations.Add(relation);
```

Comment: Thank you thank you! Now is it possible to use linq to select distinct rows but add the Price row together at the same time? or am i going to have to create a method?